Como hago para que me imprima un numero y no me salga 0
como podria resolver esta problematica, "Crea una función que reciba un número n y devuelva la suma de todos los números del 1 al n. Utiliza un bucle for para calcular la suma y muestra el resultado en la consola. *"debe imprimir solo el numero"
function sumaAcumulada(n) {}"

Bienvenido al sitio,agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.

¡Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos/trabajos. Lecturas recomendadas: [ask] y [mcve]. Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega lo que has intentado o haz una pregunta específica sobre un error o problema que tienes para implementar TU solución a la tarea/proyecto.
